# Problem conditionally showing buttons based on sibling's height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

**OBJECTIVE**

I'm developing a **UI chat interface** as a project to learn **React + TS**. When a chat message is long enough and so provides enough vertical space, its action buttons (such as *copy message*, *share*, etc.) should appear vertically stacked to the right of the message's container. **When there isn't enough space**, meaning the stacked buttons would be taller than the message's container, **the buttons shouldn't appear** at all:

[image]

**PROBLEM**

The code below isn't working. The buttons still appear as normal. Strangely, **when the window is resized, the button's visibility toggles** and they either disappear/reappear depending on whether they are currently showing (because of React's hot reload feature, either state can be the starting one).

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- Using **Lodash** to both **throttle** and **debounce** the function
- Using **useLayoutEffect** instead of **useEffect**
- Using **resize observers** instead
- Adding a very long time/debounce/throttle delay
- Using **getClientRects** instead of offsetHeight
- Talking to *ChatGPT 4*, *Phind*, *Gemini* and *Blackbox*

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import lodash from 'lodash';

// import statements removed for brevity
// props interface removed for brevity

const Message: React.FC<MessageProps> = ({ sender, messageContents, actionButtons, children }) => {
    const chatMessageRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const sideButtonsRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [showSideButtons, setShowSideButtons] = useState(true);

    const checkAndSetButtonVisibility = useCallback(() => {
        const messageContainer = chatMessageRef.current;
        const sideButtons = sideButtonsRef.current;

        if (messageContainer && sideButtons) {
            setShowSideButtons(messageContainer.offsetHeight > sideButtons.offsetHeight);
        }
    }, []);

    // Using lodash's throttle function to limit how often the checkAndSetButtonVisibility function can be invoked
    const debouncedCheck = useCallback(lodash.debounce(checkAndSetButtonVisibility, 1500), [checkAndSetButtonVisibility]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedCheck);
        checkAndSetButtonVisibility(); // Initial check for the correct state

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedCheck);
            debouncedCheck.cancel(); // Cancel any pending execution of the throttled function on cleanup
        };
    }, [debouncedCheck, checkAndSetButtonVisibility]);

    return (
        <div className={`chat-message-outer-container ${sender.toLowerCase()}`}>
            <div className="chat-message-inner-container">
                <div className="chat-message-info">
                    {sender === MessageSender.Agent ? (
                        <div className="chat-list-item-ai-model-logo-message">
                            <img className={"message-avatar"} src={aiLogo} alt="AI Model Logo" />
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="account-avatar-message">
                            <img className={"message-avatar"} src={userAvatar} alt="User avatar" />
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <div className="chat-message-info-sender">{sender}</div>
                </div>

                <div className="chat-message-select-checkbox">
                    <label className="button checkbox-field">
                        <input type="checkbox"/>
                        <span>
                      <br/>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className="chat-message-wrapper">
                    <div ref={chatMessageRef} className={`chat-message ${sender.toLowerCase()}-message`}>
                        <div className="chat-message-contents">{messageContents}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div
                    ref={sideButtonsRef}
                    className="chat-message-buttons-side"
                    style={{ display: showSideButtons ? 'flex' : 'none' }} // Use the state to control visibility
                >
                    {actionButtons}
                </div>

                <div className="chat-message-bottom">
                    {children}

                    <div className="chat-message-action-row">
                        <div className="chat-message-tag-list">
                            <Tag tagName={'Tag name'}/>

                            <AddElementButton type={"new-tag-message"}/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="chat-message-buttons-bottom">
                            {actionButtons}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, your decision whether to hide or show the buttons depends on the height of the button panel, which will change as soon as you set `display:none`, which in turn can change the visibility of the button panel. I would not be surprised if this leads to weird feedback effects.

You can try to hide the button panel by setting `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`, which should ensure the button panel keeps its height value. If the hidden element interferes with the overall layout because it still takes up space, you can additionally set `position:absolute` so the chat message input can take up the free space.